# using django orm to realize my filter

Tags: sql, django, orm, dateadd

My raw sql statement is as follows：

```
select* from t 
where dateadd(ss,closedate-datediff(ss,getdate(),getutcdate()),'1970-1-1')
      between convert (datetime,'2011-7-1 00:00:00') and convert(datetime,'2011-7-31 23:59:59')
```

closedate is one of my column in table t ,it means:seconds from 1970-1-1.

HOW can i realize this query using Django ORM?,here involved dateadd,datediff(sql server 2005) APIs,

I dont know how to handler this prob.

Comment: can you post the django model and database table schema?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do a date range query ? Something like, get all records which fall between 2 dates?
If yes, then something like the following would give you the records in the last 30days

```
today = date.today() + timedelta(days=1)
n_days_ago = today + timedelta(days=-30)
trans = Transactions.objects.filter(payment_received_date__range=[n_days_ago ,today])
```